# Group by Month and Year in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to make a query, I must receive a date and give a report in which I must show the sum of the amounts at the end of a month.

What I have so far is this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE consulta
    @fecha DATE
AS  
    SELECT  
        SUM(dca.UNIDADES) as Amount,
        MONTH(ca.FINICIO) as Month,
        YEAR(ca.FINICIO)
    FROM    
        DETALLE_CONTRATO_ALQUILER dca
    INNER JOIN 
        CONTRATOALQUILER ca ON dca.CODCONTRATO = ca.CODCONTRATO
                            AND ca.FINICIO >= @fecha
                            AND YEAR(ca.FINICIO) = YEAR(@fecha)
    GROUP BY 
        MONTH(ca.FINICIO), YEAR(ca.FINICIO)
    HAVING 
        SUM(dca.UNIDADES) > 2;
```

The comparison of years is because I only have to obtain the months of that same year.

I also attach my diagram:

[image]

The context of the database is about `product rentals`, the tables I use are the **rental contract** and the **detail**

I know I get errors because when I enter a specific date, I do not get results. I do not know what I'm failing. My query is correctly logical?

What I expect to obtain is:

```
Amount |  Month | Year
  12        1     2017
  45        2     2017
          ...
```

Here's the [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/503d7/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume all rows of both tables have matching row(s) in the other table, so an `INNER JOIN` is what you need.

There's a small detail in your query that smells fishy. Your join includes filtering conditions that may throw rows out of the query. Maybe you should place the filtering conditions in a `WHERE` clause instead of a `JOIN` clause, as in:

```
SELECT  
    SUM(dca.UNIDADES) as Amount,
    MONTH(ca.FINICIO) as Month,
    YEAR(ca.FINICIO)
FROM    
    DETALLE_CONTRATO_ALQUILER dca
INNER JOIN 
    CONTRATOALQUILER ca ON dca.CODCONTRATO = ca.CODCONTRATO
WHERE ca.FINICIO >= @fecha  -- Using WHERE instead of JOIN here!
  AND YEAR(ca.FINICIO) = YEAR(@fecha)
GROUP BY 
    MONTH(ca.FINICIO), YEAR(ca.FINICIO)
HAVING 
    SUM(dca.UNIDADES) > 2;
```

You can place filtering in the `JOIN` clause and that is very useful for `OUTER JOIN`s. However, for `INNER JOIN`s that applies to the join itself and may filter out rows you wanted to include.